# Hlsl Refract() not refracting rays correctly

Tags: unity, hlsl, raycasting

I'm making a ray tracer in unity and I'm trying to model refraction, however when I use `refract()` in my shader it doesn't change the ray direction at all.

here is a picture of the sphere I'm trying to refract, it has a transparency of (.9, .9, .9) so that it can be seen - ignore the sphere in the top right:

[image: rendered sphere]

my ray tracing compute shader

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

float4x4 _CameraToWorld;
float4x4 _CameraInverseProjection;

float4 _DirectionalLight;

float2 _PixelOffset;

Texture2D<float4> _SkyboxTexture;
SamplerState sampler_SkyboxTexture;

static const float PI = 3.14159265f;
static const float EPSILON = 1e-8;


float isAir = 1;
float nAir = 1.0f;
float nGlass = 1.5f;

//-------------------------------------
//- UTILITY

float sdot(float3 x, float3 y, float f = 1.0f)
{
    return saturate(dot(x, y) * f);
}

float energy(float3 color)
{
    return dot(color, 1.0f / 3.0f);
}

//-------------------------------------
//- RANDOMNESS

float2 _Pixel;
float _Seed;

float rand()
{
    float result = frac(sin(_Seed / 100.0f * dot(_Pixel, float2(12.9898f, 78.233f))) * 43758.5453f);
    _Seed += 1.0f;
    return result;
}


//-------------------------------------
//- SPHERES

struct Sphere
{
    float3 position;
    float radius;
    float3 albedo;
    float3 specular;
    float smoothness;
    float3 emission;
};

StructuredBuffer<Sphere> _Spheres;


//-------------------------------------
//- MESHES

struct MeshObject
{
    float4x4 localToWorldMatrix;
    int indices_offset;
    int indices_count;
    float3 albedo;
    float3 specular;
    float smoothness;
    float3 emission;
    float3 transparency;
};

StructuredBuffer<MeshObject> _MeshObjects;
StructuredBuffer<float3> _Vertices;
StructuredBuffer<int> _Indices;


//-------------------------------------
//- RAY

struct Ray
{
    float3 origin;
    float3 direction;
    float3 energy;
};

Ray CreateRay(float3 origin, float3 direction)
{
    Ray ray;
    ray.origin = origin;
    ray.direction = direction;
    ray.energy = float3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    return ray;
}

Ray CreateCameraRay(float2 uv)
{
    // Transform the camera origin to world space
    float3 origin = mul(_CameraToWorld, float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)).xyz;
    
    // Invert the perspective projection of the view-space position
    float3 direction = mul(_CameraInverseProjection, float4(uv, 0.0f, 1.0f)).xyz;
    // Transform the direction from camera to world space and normalize
    direction = mul(_CameraToWorld, float4(direction, 0.0f)).xyz;
    direction = normalize(direction);

    return CreateRay(origin, direction);
}


//-------------------------------------
//- RAYHIT

struct RayHit
{
    float3 position;
    float distance;
    float3 normal;
    float3 albedo;
    float3 specular;
    float smoothness;
    float3 emission;
    float3 transparency;
};

RayHit CreateRayHit()
{
    RayHit hit;
    hit.position = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    hit.distance = 1.#INF;
    hit.normal = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    hit.albedo = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    hit.specular = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    hit.smoothness = 0.0f;
    hit.emission = float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return hit;
}


//-------------------------------------
//- INTERSECTION

void IntersectGroundPlane(Ray ray, inout RayHit bestHit)
{
    // Calculate distance along the ray where the ground plane is intersected
    float t = -ray.origin.y / ray.direction.y;
    if (t > 0 && t < bestHit.distance)
    {
        bestHit.distance = t;
        bestHit.position = ray.origin + t * ray.direction;
        bestHit.normal = float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        bestHit.albedo = 0;
        bestHit.specular = 0.9f;
        bestHit.smoothness = 1;
        bestHit.emission = 0.2f;
        bestHit.transparency = float3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

void IntersectSphere(Ray ray, inout RayHit bestHit, Sphere sphere)
{
    // Calculate distance along the ray where the sphere is intersected
    float3 d = ray.origin - sphere.position;
    float p1 = -dot(ray.direction, d);
    float p2sqr = p1 * p1 - dot(d, d) + sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    if (p2sqr < 0)
        return;
    float p2 = sqrt(p2sqr);
    float t = p1 - p2 > 0 ? p1 - p2 : p1 + p2;
    if (t > 0 && t < bestHit.distance)
    {
        bestHit.distance = t;
        bestHit.position = ray.origin + t * ray.direction;
        bestHit.normal = normalize(bestHit.position - sphere.position);
        bestHit.albedo = float3(0, 0, 0);
        bestHit.specular = float3(0, 0, 0);
        bestHit.smoothness = 2;
        bestHit.emission = float3(0, 0, 0);
        bestHit.transparency = float3(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
    }
}

bool IntersectTriangle_MT97(Ray ray, float3 vert0, float3 vert1, float3 vert2,
    inout float t, inout float u, inout float v)
{
    // find vectors for two edges sharing vert0
    float3 edge1 = vert1 - vert0;
    float3 edge2 = vert2 - vert0;

    // begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate U parameter
    float3 pvec = cross(ray.direction, edge2);

    // if determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
    float det = dot(edge1, pvec);

    // use backface culling
    if (det < EPSILON)
        return false;
    float inv_det = 1.0f / det;

    // calculate distance from vert0 to ray origin
    float3 tvec = ray.origin - vert0;

    // calculate U parameter and test bounds
    u = dot(tvec, pvec) * inv_det;
    if (u < 0.0 || u > 1.0f)
        return false;

    // prepare to test V parameter
    float3 qvec = cross(tvec, edge1);

    // calculate V parameter and test bounds
    v = dot(ray.direction, qvec) * inv_det;
    if (v < 0.0 || u + v > 1.0f)
        return false;

    // calculate t, ray intersects triangle
    t = dot(edge2, qvec) * inv_det;

    return true;
}

void IntersectMeshObject(Ray ray, inout RayHit bestHit, MeshObject meshObject)
{
    uint offset = meshObject.indices_offset;
    uint count = offset + meshObject.indices_count;
    for (uint i = offset; i < count; i += 3)
    {
        float3 v0 = (mul(meshObject.localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i]], 1))).xyz;
        float3 v1 = (mul(meshObject.localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i + 1]], 1))).xyz;
        float3 v2 = (mul(meshObject.localToWorldMatrix, float4(_Vertices[_Indices[i + 2]], 1))).xyz;

        float t, u, v;
        if (IntersectTriangle_MT97(ray, v0, v1, v2, t, u, v))
        {
            if (t > 0 && t < bestHit.distance)
            {
                bestHit.distance = t;
                bestHit.position = ray.origin + t * ray.direction;
                bestHit.normal = ray.direction;
                bestHit.albedo = meshObject.albedo;
                bestHit.specular = meshObject.specular;
                bestHit.smoothness = meshObject.smoothness;
                bestHit.emission = meshObject.emission;
                bestHit.transparency = meshObject.transparency;
            }
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------
//- TRACE

RayHit Trace(Ray ray)
{
    RayHit bestHit = CreateRayHit();
    uint count, stride, i;

    // Trace spheres
    _Spheres.GetDimensions(count, stride);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        IntersectSphere(ray, bestHit, _Spheres[i]); // irelevant as i dont have spheres
    }

    // Trace mesh objects
    _MeshObjects.GetDimensions(count, stride);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        IntersectMeshObject(ray, bestHit, _MeshObjects[i]);
    }

    return bestHit;
}


//-------------------------------------
//- SAMPLING

float3x3 GetTangentSpace(float3 normal)
{
    // Choose a helper vector for the cross product
    float3 helper = float3(1, 0, 0);
    if (abs(normal.x) > 0.99f)
        helper = float3(0, 0, 1);

    // Generate vectors
    float3 tangent = normalize(cross(normal, helper));
    float3 binormal = normalize(cross(normal, tangent));
    return float3x3(tangent, binormal, normal);
}

float3 SampleHemisphere(float3 normal, float alpha)
{
    // Sample the hemisphere, where alpha determines the kind of the sampling
    float cosTheta = pow(rand(), 1.0f / (alpha + 1.0f));
    float sinTheta = sqrt(1.0f - cosTheta * cosTheta);
    float phi = 2 * PI * rand();
    float3 tangentSpaceDir = float3(cos(phi) * sinTheta, sin(phi) * sinTheta, cosTheta);

    // Transform direction to world space
    return mul(tangentSpaceDir, GetTangentSpace(normal));
}

//-------------------------------------
//- SHADE


float SmoothnessToPhongAlpha(float s)
{
    return pow(1000.0f, s * s);
}

float3 Shade(inout Ray ray, RayHit hit)
{
    if (hit.distance < 1.#INF)
    {
        // Calculate chances of diffuse and specular reflection
        hit.albedo = min(1.0f - hit.specular, hit.albedo);
        float specChance = energy(hit.specular);
        float diffChance = energy(hit.albedo);
        float transChance = energy(hit.transparency);

        // Roulette-select the ray's path
        float roulette = rand();
        if (roulette < specChance)
        {
            // Specular reflection
            ray.origin = hit.position + hit.normal * 0.001f;
            float alpha = SmoothnessToPhongAlpha(hit.smoothness);
            ray.direction = SampleHemisphere(reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal), alpha);
            float f = (alpha + 2) / (alpha + 1);
            ray.energy *= (1.0f / specChance) * hit.specular * sdot(hit.normal, ray.direction, f);
        }
        else if (diffChance > 0 && roulette < specChance + diffChance)
        {
            // Diffuse reflection
            ray.origin = hit.position + hit.normal * 0.001f;
            ray.direction = SampleHemisphere(hit.normal, 1.0f);
            ray.energy *= (1.0f / diffChance) * hit.albedo;
        }
        else if (roulette < transChance)
        {
            ray.origin = hit.position + hit.normal * 0.001f;
            if (isAir == 1)
                ray.direction = refract(ray.direction, hit.normal, 0.1f);
            else
                ray.direction = refract(ray.direction, hit.normal, 0.1f);
            
            ray.energy *= hit.transparency;
        }
        else
        {
            // Terminate ray
            ray.energy = 0.0f;
        }

        return hit.emission;
    }
    else
    {
        // Erase the ray's energy - the sky doesn't reflect anything
        ray.energy = 0.0f;

        // Sample the skybox and write it
        float theta = acos(ray.direction.y) / -PI;
        float phi = atan2(ray.direction.x, -ray.direction.z) / -PI * 0.5f;
        return _SkyboxTexture.SampleLevel(sampler_SkyboxTexture, float2(phi, theta), 0).xyz;
    }
}


//-------------------------------------
//- KERNEL

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    _Pixel = id.xy;

    
    // Get the dimensions of the RenderTexture
    uint width, height;
    Result.GetDimensions(width, height);

    // Transform pixel to [-1,1] range
    float2 uv = float2((id.xy + _PixelOffset) / float2(width, height) * 2.0f - 1.0f);

    // Get a ray for the UVs
    Ray ray = CreateCameraRay(uv);

    // Trace and shade the ray
    float3 result = float3(0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        RayHit hit = Trace(ray);
        result += ray.energy * Shade(ray, hit);

        if (!any(ray.energy))
            break;
    }

    Result[id.xy] = float4(result, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting the normal from the ray direction and re-adding it after the refraction?

Comment: to make the ray direction relative to the normal then back to relative to world space

Comment: That's not what subtraction of direction vectors does. Have you tried it without this?

Comment: i updated the question with the result

Comment: You removed the addition at the end too? "This isn't right as the refraction shouldn't flip the object" [Rain drops may disagree with you on this one](https://twitter.com/Jens_Starry_Sky/status/1050473646609915904?s=19), and [crystal balls too](https://www.13moons.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/82fa1d9d6e24ae87ec1eac56b72be63f/0/1/0113clearcrystalball7.jpg).

Comment: yes i removed the addition at the end also the cube i tried also totally flipped

Comment: Looks like you may want to show us a more complete view of your code so we can help isolate the problem. Can you edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example — every piece of code or scene setup instruction needed to replicate the problem in a new, empty project?

Comment: what parts do you think you would need

Comment: i have the trace function and the complete shade function, that's all that is used to calculate transparency

Comment: Create a new, empty project. Walk through the steps to demonstrate this issue in that project. Every step you take in that new project needs to be documented in your question, so that we can reproduce your problem exactly and test potential solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: this will be a problem as my scene is already empty and my ray tracer is very small

Comment: ill put the relevant parts in the question

Comment: That sounds like the absence of a problem. If your setup is so simple to reproduce, you can post the whole thing easily. You shouldn't even have to excerpt "the relevant parts" — be wary of that, as the thing you cut out as irrelevant could actually be key to understanding the problem.

Comment: ill put the entire code in a paste bin

Comment: You'll put it in your question, not in an external link that can rot and leave the question unintelligible

Comment: done ive put the compute shader in the question